# What thread-safe collection classes are available in Silverlight 4?

Tags: silverlight, thread-safety, concurrent-collections

I am developing an application framework that will be utilized by Silverlight on the client side and .NET 4 on the server side. Internally, the framework has dictionary and queue data structures where multiple threads will be accessing the collections concurrently.

On the server side, I would like to utilize the [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) and [ConcurrentQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) classes available in the [System.Collections.Concurrent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx) namespace. These classes however are not implemented in Silverlight 4.

The two approaches I am considering are:

1. Decompile the ConcurrentDictionary
   and ConcurrentQueue classes and
   implement them in a Silverlight
   class library. These would be scoped using the *System.Collections.Concurrent* namespace.
2. Implement the custom thread-safe
   collection classes I need in a shared
   library (or find a reliable
   Silverlight thread-safe collection
   implementation) that can be used both server and client side.

The first approach would allow me to just implement the Silverlight data structures that I need, but I worry about introducing disparities between my Silverlight implementation and the concurrent collection classes implemented in .NET 4.

The second approach would provide a consistent concurrent collection implementation both client and server side, but feels like I would be reinventing the wheel.

It does not appear that implementing the [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) and [ConcurrentQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) classes in Silverlight would be very difficult, but is there already a well adopted library of thread-safe collection classes for Silverlight?

Comment: Editing tags, as this still applies in SL5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this out: http://ch.codeplex.com/

Comment: That project looks great, but it doesn't appear to have a `ConcurrentQueue` implementation.  Looks like some nice code though -- I'll definitely have a read of the source.

Comment: this is well outdated project which does not include ConcurrentQueue. It looks like it is abandoned since MS release of System.Collections.Concurrent for .net4
So question still open. Is there any good implementation of ConcurrentQueue for SL5? Oppositional, did you succeed with decomplining?

Comment: Decompile while theortically possible was more difficult than I originally thought (used BCL classes not available in Silverlight). It might be easier to write collection classes from scratch, but I have not had time to try.

Comment: This has ConcurrentQueue http://robertmclaws.com/nuget-packages/system-threading-tasks-for-silverlight

Comment: @Cœur Seems to work for me. Here is a google cache as well http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Fk7Ye-zZi88J:https://ch.codeplex.com/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us

Comment: @jonperl not the answer link, the comment link to robertmclaws.com.

Answer (score 2):

The class library for Mono includes implementations of the various concurrent collections, and is licensed under the very permissive MIT license.